# Ad hoc Apple App distribution IIS7 Windows Authentication IOS 5?

Tags: authentication, iis-7, distribution, ios5, adhoc

We have a Add hoc distribution for enterprice apps by a secure website. Since version 5 we have a problem with authentication in combination with IIS7. The user logs in with a windows username and password and clicks download. Then a "*itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=domain*" action is been started.

**Before IOS 5:**
The user goes to url, types the username and password. The user press download and ***again*** the user need to type the username and password. The application is been installed.

**After installing IOS 5:** 
The user goes to url, types the username and password. The user press download and get a domain "...." not found. There is no popup again, with the credentials, like before version of IOS 5..

This solution was working for a half year, but since IOS5 it doesnt work anymore...

**IIS Log**
When going to the website and clicking on the action=download that contains the Plist file  the IIS shows 401 errors (not authenticated). But when I access the .plist or ipa file directly by url in safari I do get a POPUP to authenticate.

It look like there is a bug in IOS 5 "*itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=domain*" actions does not support to authenticate....

Answer (score 1):

Check your plist file if it points to an existing ipa file. If you're using .htaccess to authenticate with a ldap directory you'll need to authenticate once for the plist access and once for the ipa access.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a variation of the double-hop problem in which the originally supplied credentials are not being appropriately passed to the second step in your download routine (or web service call, etc.). http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx

The fact that you previously had to enter the user name and password twice would seem to support this suggestion. The error that you're receiving that domain '...' does not exist could indicate that the credential being passed to step two is a local machine account that IIS is running under.

If you can get some logging on this process I would want to determine what the authentication/credentials are that get passed at each step. It's possible that something in IOS 5 changed the way that impersonation is handled but I think that's likely just a symptom of how either IIS is set up or the final request is being passed.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. The "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=domain" doesnt trigger any credentials it looks like....

Comment: In the Before IOS 5 example, what was causing the need for the users to again enter their username and password? It seems like you must be crossing some application or security boundary as part of servicing the  action associated with the button click that generates the itms-services call.

Comment: Hi Carth, thanks for you reactie. It looks likes the "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=domain" protocol does not support windows authentication anymore....

Comment: I have created a bugreport at bugreport.apple.com. with id: 10316160. I have also created post on apple form, where other people also have this problem: https://discussions.apple.com/message/16464554#16464554

Comment: Good luck, Robert-Jan. Let us know if you manage to get a resolution.

Comment: A small update. I have created a bugreport on Apple. There have looked at the bugreport and it is linked to a other bugreport and give it the status: Duplicated. Bugreport of the duplicated case is: 9794546. The classification by Apple is: "Serious Bug"