# iOS5 app will not download with itms-services on IIS, but works on Apache

Tags: iis, ios5

I've rebuilt an iPad app to run on iOS 5. I put a link to the code on an internal apache server:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://internal.mysite.com/pages/manifest.plist
```

and it downloads fine to all of our devices running iOS 4 and iOS 5. I then put it on our Intranet site running IIS and Sharepoint

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://intranet.mysite.com/pages/manifest.plist
```

And only iOS 4 users can download it. iOS 5 users receive: Cannot connect to intranet.mysite.com when they click the link.

I've updated the MIME settings on IIS, but that didn't help. We've removed all provisioning profiles from the devices, but still it doesn't work.

The manifest.plist is updated as well to point to the intranet site and everything works on iOS 4.  Seems like iOS 5 and IIS don't get along ... any ideas?

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822597/ad-hoc-apple-app-distribution-iis7-windows-authentication-ios-5  which links to an Apple discussion: https://discussions.apple.com/message/16464554#16464554

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your IIS site allows anonymous access